Should I remove this creeping fern from my palm tree?
A creeping epiphytic fern (probably Pyrrosia piloselloides) has grown around the trunk of my palm tree (Adonidia merrillii). More than half the height of the palm's trunk is now covered by the fern. The fern also grows thickly in the area where the palm's fruits are produced, so thickly that it is able to support several bird nests. I don't mind the appearance of the fern, but I am concerned that the fern may be harming the palm. Is the fern harming the palm? Should I remove the fern?


It's pretty harmless plant and is not parasitic in nature. Which means it won't "steal" the nutrients off your host palm tree. I'd prefer to rather leave it that way as it provides a thriving ecosystem insects, birds, reptiles which in turn provide the soil near the tree with organic matter it's s essentially a mini biome itself. Additionally, it survives off decomposing wood of palm and when it dies back, it will further enrich the roots of palm with decaying matter. Let it flourish.
